# VMWare ESXI Multi Subnet Setup

Tags: vmware, esxi

I am trying to setup my home lab and I just purchased a new server. My server configuration is below

- Intel Xeon CPU E5-2620 V4 Processor Sockets 2
- Model: S2600CWR
- Network Ports: 4
- My Router IP Range is 172.16.127.1 - 172.16.127.120
- ESXI IP Address is - 172.16.127.3 (Static)
- DNS IP Address is - 172.16.127.4 (Static)
- VCenter IP Address is - 172.16.127.5 (Static)

**Current Virtual Switch**

VSwitch 0:

- Management Network

  - vmk0: 172.16.127.3
  - Physical Adapter: vmnic0
  - VLAN ID: --
- Outside Network

  - VLAN ID: --
- VM Network

  - VLAN ID: --
  - Virtual Machines(6)

    - DNS
    - SQL Linux
    - VCenter
    - SQL Server Windows 1
    - SQL Server Windows 2
    - Windows Server 2016 Template

I am not network expert guy and I am trying to setup Multi Sub Net Network with single ESXI to test the Windows Server Fail Over Cluster and SQL Server High Availability. I am trying to simulate one sql server in On-Premise and another server in data center with different sub net. At present I have installed one DNS and two SQL Servers. Before installing another DNS for Data Center and SQL Servers, I would like to setup the Network correctly.

My question is below

1. Is it possible to configure two different subnet configuration and talk to each other in single esxi? If yes, How to configure? What steps I have to follow.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple subnets configured in a single ESXi host. Most people use VLAN tagging to separate those networks, but it would require a managed switch capable of understanding VLAN tags.